# Copy SpreadsheetGear Range to html

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, spreadsheetgear

I want to copy a selected range from SpreadsheetGear Worksheet to Clipboard and then to MS Word.

Off course, I want to preserve all formating (colors, column widths . . .).

I guess I have to put it in the Clipboard in HTML format, but how do I get from SpreadsheetGear to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear does not support converting worksheet data into HTML markup.  The [IRange](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange_members.html) interface contains enough information about cell formatting (IRange.[Font](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Font.html)/[Interior](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Interior.html)/[Borders](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Borders.html)/etc) that you could probably build your own routine to generate a similar representation of the data in an HTML table, then copy this data to the Windows Clipboard.

Comment: Somehow I hoped that people had need to copy some cells as table to MS Word and that I wouldn't be the first. You're basically saying that I have to do it manually?

Comment: Since there is no built-in support for converting cell data to HTML (or any other format that would be accepted by MS Word), yes, you would have to build your own routine to do this.